# How can I read the branch deep link data via HTTP?

Tags: branch.io

Is there a way to read the deeplink data using the HTTP API?

We use the HTTP API to POST to `/v1/url` but it would be great to have a GET `/v1/url/code` to let us retrieve this data. Our use case is that we need to make the data available to our website as well as our existing mobile apps.

I've tried GET to `/v1/url/code?branch_key=key` but I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to hit the `/v1/open` or `/v1/install` endpoint in Branch's API. If someone clicks a Branch link tied to your account, you'll need to hit those endpoints every time the app opens to see if the person opening the app came from a Branch link click.

For iOS, the simplest way to do this is to create an `NSRequest` inside your `AppDelegate.m`, right inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. This request should contain certain parameters inside the body that the Branch endpoint is expecting, such as your branch key, IP address, OS version, etc.

The callback after a request completes, if it's a `200`, will contain the deeplink data you packed inside link.

Reference [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-SDKLess-API). Branch info [here](http://branch.io).

Comment: Thanks but I need to get this information on our website for when a user clicks the branch link and chooses to go to our website rather than app. Therefore there is no `hardware_id` or `device_fingerprint_id` available etc. I'm just looking for the complementary call to the `POST` for `/v1/url`.

Comment: The best solution is to use the web SDK if you'd like this information on your website: https://dev.branch.io/references/web_sdk/ You can retrieve the deep link data exactly the same as in a native app, using a callback.